# Is there a framework/service for working with a publish/subscribe pattern and WCF?

Tags: wcf, msmq, publish-subscribe

My team are looking for ways to separate the various components of our system to decoupled services. What we'd like to achieve is an event-driven pattern where services subscribe to receive information sent when events occur in other systems.

Since we're already using WCF for our request-reply messaging, we'd like to continue using it for this particular pattern. Ideally, the messages would be managed via MSMQ to enable us to use reliable messaging to give us fault tolerance in the event of a service failure.

We're not looking for anything complicated like transactional support across service boundaries. Really, we just need a simple subscription-based message dispatch system. Are there any simple frameworks or services which can help us work to this pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest is NServiceBus (http://www.nservicebus.com/PubSub.aspx) but this does not use WCF.

However from a integration perspective sending and receiving messages is far simpler than the messaging semantics on web services, so you don't need WCF to abstract that away.

Edit: In order to enable this using NetMsmqBinding you will have to implement the subscription infrastructure yourself. It would also be fairly easy to do.

Your publisher would need to have a database to store the subscriptions. When your subscribers start up, the first thing they do is send a subscription message to the publisher, who logs the subscription in it's subscription db.

The subscription messages should contain:

1. The message types I am interested in
2. My queue address

Then when your publisher wants to publish a message it retrieves the subscriptions and evaluates each one to see if the message matches the subscription and to retrieve the address to send to. Then it just sends the messages.

This is a standard pattern for implementing pub sub.

Comment: Architecturally, the abstraction WCF provides between service and binding is very clean, and I'd prefer we continued to use it if possible. NServiceBus looks neat though. Do you know if you can just use the subscribe components directly and leave the publishing to native MSMQ?

Comment: I have expanded my answer above with a possible pattern you could use to implement this. In answer to your comment, no I don't think it's possible to use the subscription infrastructure without the rest of it, although the project is open source so you could always try.